# estou tentanto enviar um formlario sem a ultilização do input submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formulário, lógica

Queria saber se e possível submeter um `<form>` em via de texto tipo:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    NOME
</form>
```

Quando clicar no texto NOME ele deverá submeter o formulário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa um `label` com um `for` para um `input:submit` que está oculto com `display:none`. Assim quando vc clica no `label` ele aciona o `submit`. Com essa técnica não precisa de JS

```css
#subi {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="action.php">
    <label for="subi" role="button" aria-label="enviar">nome</label>
    <input id="subi" hidden type="submit" value="envia">
</form>
```

**OBS:** Só tenha em mente como vc vai tratar a semântica e acessibilidade disso... Recomendo que use o [`role`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) e o [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) e coloque tb o atributo [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) no `input` que vc quer esconder dos leitores de tela

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um evento com `javascript` (`jQuery`) com um gatilho no campo que quiser, desde que possa identifica-lo de alguma forma. Exemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="formulario">
    <div id="submeter">NOME</div> 
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#submeter').on('click', function(){
        $('#formulario').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```